# Buffer object and image buffer object in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

What is the difference between Buffer object and image buffer object in opencl? It is evident that image buffer is faster but to what extent? Where they must be used?

Comment: FYI, starting from OpenCL 2.x, image object can be read-write.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An OpenCL Buffer is a 1D or 2D or 3D array in global memory.  Its an abstract  object
that can be addressed thru a pointer.  Buffers are Read-Only or Write_only or Read-Write.
 An Image buffer represents GPU Texture memory.   It represents an array of pixels that
can be access via  functions specifying  pixel x,y,z coordinates. There is no pointer access to Image Pixels on the GPU.

The hardware treats these two type of buffers differently.  A OpenCL Buffer is either in
Host RAM or GPU RAM and transferred between the two.  A  OpenCL Image Buffer has analogous
characteristics of a OpenCL Buffer. But the differences are Image Buffer are either Read-only or Write-only.  For Read-only Image buffers, the GPU can cache copies of the image pixels in every compute unit (=  32 or 64 ALU ). Typical  the cache size is 8K (bytes or pixels?).
Also,  since image pixels cannot be accessed via a pointer on the GPU.  Their mapping from
x,y,z  coordinates to physical address  can be mapped in several ways.  One way is to a Z-ordering.  This clusters  pixels in two dimensions so that  neighboring pixels in
x,y directions are store linearly.  This helps  speed  access neighboring pixels in
image filters.

OpenCL Buffers are used for general arrays and especially for arrays that are read-write,
or double precision. 
OpenCL Image Buffers are used for image processing or other signal processing algos
where the input image/signal can treated as read-only.

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay. Learnt a lot , but also wanted to know which one is faster and by what percentage

Comment: There is no generic answer to the which is faster and by what %. It depends on  how your code accesses memory and what device you run on.

Comment: I think I can do the image processing without using Image buffers at all, can I? They are helpfull but not necessary as cl API.